# How to install fuerte's latest pcl(1.6?) on ros electric?

Tags: pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use electric, but I need to use the latest pcl(1.6).

So I want to install fuerte's pcl stack on ros electric.

How to install it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42170/how-to-install-fuerte%27s-latest-pcl(1.6?)-on-ros-electric?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`perception-pcl-fuerte-unstable` maintainer here. You'll have to [build it from source](https://bitbucket.org/macmason/perception_pcl_fuerte_unstable), and troubleshoot whatever problems come along from not being on Fuerte.

This may, or may not, be straightforward.

Out of curiosity, why Electric?

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-23**:
Because I already installed electric,and unable to upgrade ubuntu version.

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-08-24**:
Good reason!